# duplicity --progress not working properly

Tags: backup, 18.04, duplicity

So I've been using the command `duplicity ~ gdocs://my_folder_here` to back up my /home folder to Google Drive periodically, and recently ran into the `--progress` argument that is supposed to show me the progress of the backup. However, when I tried using it, the result was very different from what I expected: it just keeps printing an empty loading bar every three seconds and `ETA Stalled!` and eventually the 100% bar when the backup completes.

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Is there any way for me to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried fixing the error? Maybe that's messing up the progress bar.

Comment: I removed the .dbus folder, error is gone but it didn't affect the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very long standing bug in duplicity (since at least 2015). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1482841